# Replace duplicate numbers with unique numbers from 0-(N-1)

Tags: java, algorithm

### Background:

I have an N-length array of positive random numbers that are certain to contain duplicates.
e.g. 10,4,5,7,10,9,10,9,8,10,5
**Edit**: *N is likely to be 32, or some other power of two about that size.*

### The Problem:

I am trying to find the fastest way to replace the duplicates with the missing numbers from 0-(N-1). Using the above example, I want a result that looks like this:
10,4,5,7,0,9,1,2,8,3,6
The goal being to have one of each number from 0 to N-1, without just replacing all the numbers with 0-(N-1) (the random order is important).
**Edit**: *It's also important that this replacement is deterministic, i.e. the same input will have the same output (not random).*

### My solution:

Currently implemented in Java, uses 2 boolean arrays to keep track of used/unused numbers (unique numbers/missing numbers in the range [0,N) ), and has an approximate worst-case runtime of N+N*sqrt(N).
The code follows:

```
public byte[] uniqueify(byte[] input)
{
    boolean[] usedNumbers = new boolean[N];
    boolean[] unusedIndices = new boolean[N];
    byte[] result = new byte[N];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) // first pass through
    {
        int newIdx = (input[i] + 128) % N; // first make positive
        if(!usedNumbers[newIdx]) // if this number has not been used
        {
            usedNumbers[newIdx] = true; // mark as used
            result[i] = newIdx; // save it in the result
        }
        else // if the number is used
        {
            unusedIndices[i] = true; // add it to the list of duplicates
        }
    }

    // handle all the duplicates
    for(int idx = 0; idx < N; idx++) // iterate through all numbers
    {
        if(unusedIndices[idx]) // if unused
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) // go through all numbers again
            {
                if(!usedNumbers[i]) // if this number is still unused
                {
                    usedNumbers[i] = true; // mark as used
                    result[i] = idx;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This seems like the fastest I can hope for, but I thought I'd ask the internet, because there are people much more clever than I who may have a better solution.

N.B. Suggestions/solutions do not have to be in Java.

Thank you.

**Edit**: *I forgot to mention that I am converting this to C++. I posted my java implementation because it's more complete.*

Comment: Is it important what order the *missing* numbers are inserted? What is the likely length of the list?

Comment: @Borodin  
The order of inserting the missing numbers is only important insofar as that it is deterministic; in other words, given the same input array, we should get the same output each time.  
The length is 32 bytes, or some other small power of two. (less than 1024)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to do this is probably the most straightforward one. I would take a pass through the list of data keeping a count of each distinct value and marking where duplicates appeared. Then it is just a matter of forming a list of unused values and applying them in turn at the places where duplicates were found.

Tempting as it may be to use a C++ `List`, if speed is of the essence a simple C array is the most efficient.

This program show the principle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int data[] = { 10, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 10, 9, 8, 10, 5 };
  int N = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);

  int tally[N];
  memset(tally, 0, sizeof(tally));

  int dup_indices[N];
  int ndups = 0;

  // Build a count of each value and a list of indices of duplicate data
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (tally[data[i]]++) {
      dup_indices[ndups++] = i;
    }
  }

  // Replace each duplicate with the next value having a zero count
  int t = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < ndups; i++) {
    while (tally[t]) t++;
    data[dup_indices[i]] = t++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cout << data[i] << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
10 4 5 7 0 9 1 2 8 3 6
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a [balanced binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_binary_search_tree) to keep track of used/unused numbers instead of a boolean array. Then you're running time will be `n log n`.

The most straightforward solution would be this:

1. Go through the list and build the "unused" BST
2. Go through the list a second time, keeping track of numbers seen so far in a "used" BST
3. If a duplicate is found, replace it with a random element of the "unused" BST.

Comment: You could use a hash map, and replace with the smallest element from the "unused".

Comment: For larger sets of data, I think this is a good solution. However, for the size I am dealing with (about 32 items) I think the memory management overhead would be slower than the algorithm itself.
A hash map might be better suited for sets of this size because of constant look-up time, and they'll be smaller and less complex in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would write it.

```
public static int[] uniqueify(int... input) {
    Set<Integer> unused = new HashSet<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) unused.add(j);
    for (int i : input) unused.remove(i);
    Iterator<Integer> iter = unused.iterator();
    Set<Integer> unique = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (int i : input)
        if (!unique.add(i))
            unique.add(iter.next());
    int[] result = new int[input.length];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i : unique) result[k++] = i;
    return result;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(uniqueify(10, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 10, 9, 8, 10, 5)));
}
```

prints

```
[10, 4, 5, 7, 0, 9, 1, 2, 8, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be 
1. copy the array to a Set in Java.

Set will automatically remove duplicates in the fastest complexity possible(because Sun Micro has implemented it, generally their approach is the fastest like.. use of TimSort for sorting etc...)

1. Calculate size() of the set.
2. the size will give you no of duplicates present.
3. now copy array 0-n-1 to the same set... the missing values will get inserted.

Comment: This won't preserve the order of elements.

Comment: Also, depending on the Set you use, size() isn't a constant time operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is even possible with running time `n`. The idea is to keep track of items used in the original list and additional items used during processing in a separate array. A possible java implementation looks like this:

```
int[] list = { 10, 4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 10, 9, 8, 10, 5 };

boolean[] used = new boolean[list.length];
for (int i : list) {
    used[i] = true;
}

boolean[] done = new boolean[list.length];
int nextUnused = 0;

Arrays.fill(done, false);

for (int idx = 0; idx < list.length; idx++) {
    if (done[list[idx]]) {
        list[idx] = nextUnused;
    }
    done[list[idx]] = true;
    while (nextUnused < list.length && (done[nextUnused] || used[nextUnused])) {
        nextUnused++;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
```

Comment: The problem here is that `nextUnused` might be used later in the array. There's really no getting away from the scan-replace paradigm here.

Comment: @jpm You're right. Have a look at the modified the code which does not first scan the original list. Still the running time is linear.

Comment: I'm guessing by not, you meant now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> needsReplaced = newLinkedList<Integer>();
boolean[] seen = new boolean[input.length];

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    if (seen[input[i]]) {
        needsReplaced.add(i);
    } else {
        seen[input[i]] = true;
    }

}

int replaceWith = 0;
for (int i : needsReplaced) {
    while (seen[replaceWith]) {
        ++replaceWith;
    }
    input[i] = replaceWith++;
}
```

This should behave in about 2n. The list operations are constant time, and even though that second loop looks nested, the outer loop runs significantly less than n iterations, and the inner loop will only run a total of n times.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>C# but should be easy to convert to java.</strike> O(n).

```
        int[] list = { 0, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
        int N = list.length;

        boolean[] InList = new boolean[N];
        boolean[] Used = new boolean[N];
        int[] Unused = new int[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) InList[list[i]] = true;
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < N; i++) 
            if (InList[i] == false)
                Unused[j++] = i;

        int UnusedIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (Used[list[i]] == true)
                list[i] = Unused[UnusedIndex++];
            Used[list[i]] = true;
        }
```

Edit: tried to convert it to java from c#. I don't have java here so it may not compile but should be easy to fix. The arrays may need to be initialized to false if java doesn't do that automatically.